# Calloc/Malloc error

Tags: c, memory, malloc, calloc

I am trying to write a program, but every time I try allocating memory, the 4th member of other array loses its meaning. Here is my code:

At first I read file with integer type numbers: In example. 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3

```
int* reading (int* numbers, char* arg2[])
int* fuction(int* numbers);

int main(int arg1, char *arg2[] ){
    if(arg1 != 2){return 0;}
    int *numbers;
    numbers = reading(numbers, arg2);
    numbers = function(numbers);
    return 0;
}

int* reading (int* numbers, char* arg2[]){
    FILE *in=fopen(arg2[1], "r");
    if (in == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file !\n");
        exit(1);
    } 

    int data, length = 1;

    numbers = (int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
    while (fscanf(in, "%d", &data) != EOF){
        numbers[length] = data;
        length++;
        numbers = realloc(numbers, length+1);
    }

    numbers[0] = length;
    numbers[0]--;
    return numbers;
}

int* fuction(int* numbers){

    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int* places;
    places = (int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
    places[0] = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= numbers[0]; i++){ sum += numbers[i];}
    if((((numbers[0]) % 3) > 0) || ((sum % ((numbers[0])/3)) > 0)){return places;}

    sum = sum / ((numbers[0])/3); 
    int* newNumbers;
    for(i = 1;i<=numbers[0];i++){printf("%d ", numbers[i]);}
        printf("\n");
```

Here in cmd I see: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3

```
    newNumbers = calloc(numbers[0]+1,sizeof(int) );
        for(i = 1;i<=numbers[0];i++){printf("%d ", numbers[i]);}
        printf("\n");
```

But after allocating memory for newNumbers(I tried both - malloc and calloc), I see result like this: 1 2 3 102506522 2 3 1 2 3

```
    places = realloc(places, numbers[0]+1);

    for(i = 1;i<=numbers[0];i++){printf("%d ", numbers[i]);}
        printf("\n");
```

Here result stays the same: 1 2 3 102506522 2 3 1 2 3

```
}
```

Writing like this:

```
places = realloc(places, numbers[0]+1);
newNumbers = calloc(numbers[0]+1,sizeof(int) );
```

I mean allocating memory for "places" at first,
does not solve my problem as well. After:

```
newNumbers = calloc(numbers[0]+1,sizeof(int) );
```

I lose numbers[4]- meaning.

I can't understand why it is happening. Maybe someone could help me and give me an advice, how could I correct it.

Comment: In C arrays are indexed starting at zero....

Comment: And don't cast `malloc()` result, and don't use `realloc()` that way it could cause a memory leak. And `1*sizeof(int)` ... WTF?

Comment: Why do all new programmers to C feel the need to type cast malloc()?  Is there a tutorial out there that is teaching this?

Comment: When you return a pointer to memory that was allocated on the heap, you can use a local variable for that pointer. There's no need to pass that pointer in (uninitialised).

Comment: array[0] member I use in my program as a length of an array

Comment: `numbers = realloc(numbers, length+1);` --> `numbers = realloc(numbers, (length+1)*sizeof(int));`

Comment: the passed parameter (any passed parameter) is just a copy of the actual value used in the call to the function.  changing data at the target of a pointer works very well.  However, to change the pointer itself, the call statement needs to pass the address of the pointer and the called function needs to use: ( int **number.   )

Comment: it is very wise to use meaningful names for functions and for variables (although single letter names for indexes, like i,j,k are acceptable for statements like: 'for( i=0; i<maxValue;i++ )'.  certain parameter names, such as those for int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) are well known.  using other names for those parameters is confusing and just make the code harder to understand/debug.  function names like: 'fuction' are meaningless and add not value what so ever to the code.  Use meaningful names, usually including a active verb to indicate the purpose of the function.

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc (and family of functions) before using that value.

Comment: regarding this line: 'sum = sum / ((numbers[0])/3);' if numbers is less than 3, then this will result in division by zero.  this is because a divide operator will use the mode of the surrounding values and if the surrounding values are integers, it will be an integer divide and the result will be an integer,  I.E. 5/3 would be 1, not 1.33

Comment: @user3629249 about function name "function" - this was just random name, that came into my mind while posting this question, but thank you for other mentioned remarks.

Comment: Consider not using `sizeof(int)`, but this style: `newNumbers = calloc(numbers[0]+1,sizeof *newNumbers );`.  It is easier to code and maintain.